# File storage with multiple build flavours

Tags: android, file-storage

In my application I make use of two build flavours / build variants. After switching to two build flavours, a bug was introduced in my application. I have now discovered the reason for this bug, but I am unable to find a solution.

The situation:

In my MainActivity class, I have a function that checks if a file exists - it is very straightforward;

```
public boolean fileExists(String filename) {
    File file = null;
    file = this.getApplicationContext().getFileStreamPath(filename);
    return file.exists();
}
```

Using the debugger, location of the file is reported as: /data/data/foo.bar.appname.**buildflavour**/files/filename

In another class, I try to write to this same location;

```
outputStream = getActivity().getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
outputStream.write("test");
outputStream.close();
```

However, when I print the following line in front of the outputStream `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` - context is reported as; com.foo.bar.appname@14fcdd18. Therefore, I believe that these two classes are trying to save / retrieve a file in different locations. Any ideas on how I can make sure that the application is writing the file in the correct build flavour location? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `com.foo.bar.appname@14fcdd18` doesn't look like a file system path. How would you even get the location of an `OutputStream`?

Comment: @toKrause Correct, updated for clarity.

Comment: @WalterB please clarify again your current problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to use different application id.

Form official site [Configuring Gradle Builds](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html)

> When using build variants, the build system enables you to uniquely identify different packages for each product flavors and build types.
>
> ```
>  productFlavors {
>     pro {
>         applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.pro"
>     }
>     free {
>         applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.free"
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Yes I believe this is the key, but I am unsure how this can be achieved. Should `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` in my second class somehow be replaced with a hardcoded string? That does not seem like the best coding idea though.

Comment: you would add that into your `build.gradle` and you will have 2 different packages for your app, of course use your own names

Comment: Thank you for your help - but I already have these two different packages for my app. However, I have the code of the both classes mentioned in my original post inside a 'shared' folder. For some reason MainActivity is able to retrieve the productFlavor correctly, and my other class is not.

Comment: then everything would work like a charm, please provide your `build.gradle`

Comment: This is the productFlavors part of `build.gradle`.

`productFlavors {
    one {
        applicationId "com.foo.applicationname.one"
        versionName "1.0-one"
    }
    two {
        applicationId "com.foo.applicationname.two"
        versionName "1.0-two"
}}`

Comment: but your initial question refers to `com.foo.bar.appname`? where is truth?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I was able to find the answer to my question. Initially I was calling a function in MainActivity onCreate, but this function was no longer being called because the buildFlavors redirected directly to one of my application fragments.

To anyone coming here with a similar problem: verify that your Flavors call the necessary functions and classes.